# How can you convert blank spaces to &nbsp;?

Tags: javascript

Without using regular expressions, how can you convert blank spaces to `&nbsp;`?

Comment: What is your purpose behind doing this?

Comment: So, can we or can we not use regular expressions? Your question is a bit fuzzy.

Comment: Sorry guys, i found the solution from answers below. Actually replace() does work.

Comment: @Frankel so pick an answer so the person gets the reputation they deserve please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
"this is a string".replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;')
```

Comment: Hmmm... just another bug in the Markdown impl.

Comment: The question did specify "without regular expressions" - and /\s/ is one.

Comment: True, see below for an example of one without regex. This has the added benefit of converting other whitespace unicode characters (non-breaking spaces, etc) in one fell swoop.

Comment: It looks like the &nbsp bug is fixed, changed the comment accordingly.

Answer (score 18):

You can do it *without* regular expressions using

`"This is a string".split(" ").join("&nbsp;");`

Comment: If performance is your goal, since you don't want to use regex, it's worth thinking about the memory aspects of this if you're doing it a lot. In C# this would result in lots of unnecessary string allocations meaning more GC work. I don't know if the same is true for javascript but worth considering. But if you just want something consice this is nice.

Comment: And worth looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript where they discuss performance