# javascript function to replace space

Tags: javascript, html, encode, space

Hi can you give me a javascript function to replace spaces with `&nbsp;`

i googled and can't get them to work. I'm currently using this function:

```
  function escapeHTMLEncode(str) 
        {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            var text = document.createTextNode(str);
            div.appendChild(text);
            return div.innerHTML;
        }
```

Comment: This code works for characters which must actually be escaped in HTML, such as `>` (escaped as `&gt;`). But `&nbsp;` is not the same thing as a space character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you convert blank spaces to &nbsp; in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170154/how-can-you-convert-blank-spaces-to-nbsp-in-javascript)

Comment: \s matches whitespace (spaces, tabs and new lines).

Comment: Have a look at [Convert special characters to HTML in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
return str.replace(/\s+/g, '&nbsp;');
```

However, the name of your function, `escapeHTMLEncode`, suggests you want to do more than just replace spaces. Can you clarify your question? See also [Convert special characters to HTML in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript), which seems to be what you're trying to do.

Note that the `\s+` pattern will match any sequence of consecutive whitespace. If you want to replace only space characters (), and replace *each* of them with `&nbsp;`, use

```
return str.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');
```

Comment: my function replaces <,>,",& with &lt; &gt; &quot; &amp; however it doesn't replace spaces with &nbsp

Comment: Might be better to use `/ /g` - OP probably doesn't want to replace all whitespace, just actual space characters. Also I suspect each individual space should be replaced, not each group of spaces, so no `+`. @aedz - changing a space to `&nbsp;` is not "escaping".

Answer (score 0):

```
function escapeHTMLEncode(str) 
 {
   var reg = new RegExp(" ","g");//remove only space 
   return   str.replace(reg,"&nbsp;");//replace space with &nbsp;
  }
```